# Postgres 11 - *prioritized* where clause in group

Tags: postgresql

table below is given:

```
create table cafes (
  id uuid not null
    constraint cafes_pkey primary key,
  identity uuid not null,

  is_closed boolean,
  is_illegal boolean
)
```

The problem is to select one cafe from each group (grouped by `identity`), which:

- priority #1: has `is_closed = true`
- priority #2: has `is_illegal = true`

That is, if we have a closed cafe, we select it. If there are no such cafes in group, we search by `is_illegal = true`.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? :)

Comment: What if you have several cafees that are closed, choose a random one?

Comment: Don't choose anything :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booleans can be ORDERED BY just like other types, with false coming before true when no direction is given.

You could use this in a DISTINCT ON, or in a LATERAL join.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (identity), * 
from cafes 
ORDER BY identity, is_closed DESC NULLS last
       , is_illegal DESC NULLS last
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add an answer with a different technique than @jjanes. DISTINCT ON is specific for PostgreSQL (which is what you are using), so consider this a complement to to that:

```
select id, identity, is_closed, is_illegal
, row_number() over (partition by identity 
                     order by case when is_closed then 2 else 0 end + 
                              case when is_illegal then 1 else 0 end) as rn
from cafes;
```

You can construct the order by so that your preferred rows comes first in each partition. The add an outer select for the lowest rn:s

```
select id, identity, is_closed, is_illegal
from (
    select id, identity, is_closed, is_illegal
    , row_number() over (partition by identity 
                         order by case when is_closed then 2 else 0 end + 
                                  case when is_illegal then 1 else 0 end) as rn
    from cafes
) as t
where rn = 1;
```